# Why does CSS width:100% cause horizontal scrolling?

Tags: css, height, width, overflow

Okay, so, on my website, I have three panels: cont1, cont2, and cont3. The following are their CSS definitions:

```
#cont1 { width:35%; position:fixed; background:#2583FE; right:0px; overflow:hidden; float:right; border:1px solid #0961D3; border-left:0px solid black; height:100%;}

#cont2 { height:69%; width:100%; overflow:auto;}

#cont3 { min-height:75px; width:100%; position:relative; display:block;}
```

Now, if I implement it in the following way, only a vertical scrollbar appears and I can scroll my content as I wish:

```
<div id="cont1">
     <div id="cont3">First element</div>
     <div id="cont3">Second element</div>
     <div id="cont3">Third Element</div>
     <!--And so on-->
</div>
```

However, if I implement it in this way (the way that I ultimately want it to work), horizontal scrollbars appear in cont2 for no apparent reason:

```
<div id="cont1">
     <div id="cont2">
           <div id="cont3">First element</div>
           <div id="cont3">Second element</div>
           <div id="cont3">Third Element</div>
           <!--And so on-->
     </div>
</div>
```

Usually, I would just put overflow-x:hidden, but I'm trying to make my site as cross platform as possible and I know overflow-x is a CSS3 property (not supported in IE8 or below). Could anyone offer insight as to what might be happening? Thank you!

Comment: I'd imagine cont 2 is getting assigned margins by the browsers. Try setting `margin: 0` Why do you have cont2 though, it seems to be superfluous.

Comment: problem not clear as http://jsfiddle.net/5tQhA/ is seems to be fine

Comment: You don't have any paddings or margins that could cause the total width needed to be larger than the available width? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5tQhA/1/)

Comment: Mr. Lister, I have my margins for each cont3 set at 10px, but even without margins I am still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
.cont{
height: 30px;/**/
border-color: black;
/*position: relative;*/
position: fixed;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
width: 100%;
border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin, you must use the `#id` once, there can be only one `#id`. Uses `.classes` if you want to put several.

Then I do not understand I do not have this problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXfk2/), I wonder if this is the edge that is used in `#cont1` that you created this bar.

You have a page to show us the problem live?

Comment: This should have been a comment. Would have made a good comment too.

Comment: Im, sorry, I don't, but I believe the reason the problem is not being recreated in your fiddle is because I have so many cont3 elements that I run over the height of the container. I showed three in my code above just as an example. I actually have 25 haha but found it pointless to copy and paste so many times.